# Nest typeorm migrations SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

Can you help me to resolve this without using the .js extension in migrations option? i have tested this project and it works good https://github.com/Ferdysd96/nestjs-permission-boilerplate but in mine i have this error in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: More than likely you have a `migrations` config in the `TypeOrmModule.forRoot/Async()` that points to a `ts` file when it should only be pointing to `js` or there should be a separate config for migrations

Comment: @jayMcDoniel yes in my config it is pointing in `.ts` but i have the same config of migrations same here ` https://github.com/Ferdysd96/nestjs-permission-boilerplate`
in this poject it works perfectly but in mine i have the problem

Comment: [That config doesn't have a `migrations` property](https://github.com/Ferdysd96/nestjs-permission-boilerplate/blob/master/src/database/database.providers.ts#L8) unless I've missed it somewhere

Comment: @JayMcDoniel `https://github.com/Ferdysd96/nestjs-permission-boilerplate/blob/master/.env.example`

Comment: Okay, so what's different about your config (which still hasn't been shown) and this repo you keep pointing to?

Comment: i added this
```
  migrations: [config.get('TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS')],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: config.get('TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR'),
  },```

Comment: That's going to try to add the migrations when you start up the application instead of just reading from process.env when using the typeorm CLI. This is why you're having an issue